# How to hardcode Cluster Name to a Databricks JSON

Tags: github, jenkins, databricks, azure-databricks, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a JSON file for running jobs on Databricks via Jenkins. It follows the standard format

```
Name of the job:
New Cluster:
Env. parameters:
Libraries:
Notebook Name:
Email Notification:
```

Is there any way to hardcode a pre-existing cluster name to the JSON file so that I can avoid creating a new cluster?

PS: The env. params and library details are configured onto my pre-existing cluster.

Comment: what integration are you using that uses such JSON file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `existing_cluster_id` parameter of the Jobs API instead of using `new_cluster` ([API docs](https://redocly.github.io/redoc/?url=https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/_static/api-refs/jobs-2.1-azure.yaml#operation/JobsCreate)).  Actual name in JSON depends on the integration that you're using inside Jenkins - it could be something written by your team...